# Registering classes in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created the classes called HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector.cs and HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector.cs inside the Controllers liked showed in the article [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api)

```
public class HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector()
    {
    }
    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        HttpActionDescriptor decriptor = null;
        try
        {
            decriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            var code = ex.Response.StatusCode;
            if (code != HttpStatusCode.NotFound && code != HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
                throw;
            var routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Handle404";
            IHttpController httpController = new ErrorController();
            controllerContext.Controller = httpController;
            controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(controllerContext.Configuration, "Error", httpController.GetType());
            decriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        }
        return decriptor;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector: DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    public HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration): base(configuration)
    {
    }
    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
     HttpControllerDescriptor decriptor = null;
     try
        {
            decriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {
         var code = ex.Response.StatusCode;
         if (code != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            throw;
         var routeValues = request.GetRouteData().Values;
         routeValues["controller"] = "Error";
         routeValues["action"] = "Handle404";
         decriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        return decriptor;
    }
}
}
```

where ErrorController.cs is

```
public class ErrorController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = "The requested resource is not found";
        return Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "The requested resource is not found" });
    }
}
```

But to register the custom IHttpControllerSelector and IHttpActionSelector in the global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector(configuration));
        configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector());
    }
}
```

It throws the below exception
[image]

On the Lines

```
   configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector(configuration));
   configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your global.asax:

- Add `using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;`
- Replace `configuration` with `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

You can register them in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), 
    new Controllers.HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector(config));
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), 
    new Controllers.HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector());
```